# Как реализуются иммутабельные записи в БД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, архитектура, entity-framework-core

При реализации проекта/схемы БД небольшой/тривиальной бухгалтерской программы возникла следующая проблема. Представим себе несколько таблиц в БД (пока не обращайте внимание на типы, можно взять за пример [БД Northwind](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs) от Microsoft):

```
+----------------+    +------------------+    +-----------+
| Product        |    | OrderDetails     |    | Order     |
+--------+-------+    +------+-----------+    +------+----+
| guid   | Id    |<-+ | guid | OrderId   |--->| guid | Id |
+--------+-------+  | +------+-----------+    +------+----+
| string | Name  |  +-| guid | ProductId |
+--------+-------+    +------+-----------+
| int    | Price |    | int  | Amount    |
+--------+-------+    +------+-----------+
```

Так как предполагается генерация документов на основе данных из БД, то возникает логичный вопрос: а как повторно сгенерировать документ, если информация о продукте изменилась? В этом случае (как мне представляется) есть пара вариантов:
а) после генерации документа сохранять его в файловой системе (в этом случае теряется вся информация, т.е. мы не можем гарантировать, что данные не изменились со времени генерации документа);
б) сохранять всю информацию непосредственно в БД. Не будет ли в этом случае трудно поддерживать и сопровождать БД?

Как принято поступать в таких случаях?

---

#### Добавление

Сейчас в голову пришёл ещё один вариант. Во все сущности, которые должны сохранять своё состояние добавляем свойство указывающее на текущее состояние ItemState (например: Draft, Active, Inactive, Deleted). Также добавляем свойство ItemCode, которое указывает на конкретную сущность (не путать с Id). Далее это можно было бы использовать так:

а) пользователь создаёт счёт-фактуру, которая ссылается на конкретные записи в БД;
б) если пользователь в дальнейшем изменяет цену товара, то в БД выполняется следующая транзакция:

1. Запись товара копируется в БД и получает новый Guid, но сохраняет свой ItemCode;
2. ItemState "старой" сущности меняется с Active на Inactive;

В приведённом примере все используемые "старые" ссылки (например в существующих счетах-фактурах) будут ссылаться на "старые" данные. То есть основная идея в том, что сущности не изменяются в БД, а копируются. Можно ли использовать такой подход? Может быть у этого подхода есть своё название (даже не знаю как это "нагуглить")?

---

P.S.: не знаю поможет ли эта информация, но используется EF Core 3.1, MS SQL.

Comment: `Не будет ли в этом случае трудно поддерживать и сопровождать БД?` не думаю, насколько я понял, по вашей схеме, меняться может только цена у продукта, тогда вы можете сохранять её в orderdetails (или общую в order), тогда при изменение продукта заказ не будет меняться, а соответственно и отчет тоже, менять готовый заказ вообще плохая идея, т.к. не понятно правда ли хранится в базе или нет

Comment: @ExplodingKitten схема приведена как пример взаимосвязей, а меняться может что угодно. В том-то и дело, что меняться будет не заказ/оферта/договор/счёт, а сущности, на который он ссылается. У того же клиента может измениться адрес или другая информация, которая используется при генерации документа.

Comment: Нельзя для ваших таблиц создать специальные таблицы истории? Писать в эти таблицы весь аудит, что вам нужен, кто и когда и что поменял. А основные таблицы оставить как есть и не пачкать аудитом?

Comment: @tym32167 привет! Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае нет смысла сохранять какую-либо информацию в основных таблицах, а сразу сохранять в таблицу аудита? Может подскажешь пример реализации или информацию об этом?

Comment: Привет!  Да, это обычные таблицы истории, ничего при этом не надо менять в основных таблицах. Структура таких таблиц истории всегда зависит от требований задачи. Реализация лога также может быть разная. Когда то, лет 10 назад, мы писали триггеры на таблицы в SQL Server, которые автоматом на любой insert или update в основной таблице добавляли запись в таблицу-историю. В твоем случае могут быть какие то другие требования, но идея та же самая.

Comment: Другой вариант - это пересмотр архитектуры на событийную ([Even Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)), такое применяется обычно вместе с CQRS. При таком подходе все изменения системы пишутся в таблицу событий, а состояние самой системы строится на основе потока событий. Таким образом, накатывая и отменяя события, можно крутить состояние системы вперед и назад, а сами события представляют собой полную историю изменений. Но это уже сложная тема и я не думаю, что это то, что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Подходы, которые упомянули в комментариях могут сработать, но не все и всегда практичны, когда нужно поддерживать именно доступ к данным в какой-то момент времени в прошлом. Т.е. да, по истории или аудиту, можно восстановить состояние, на тот момент. Но если уже какая-то часть кода реализована, то это потребует дополнительной поддержки по восстановлению этого состояния, нужно все равно идентифицировать версии и т.д.

Event sourcing выглядит хорошо, но его добавление в готовую систему, требует еще больше усилий. Без опыта использования event sourcing внедрить непросто.

Есть еще один подход, который стоит рассмотреть, и вы его частично описали в вопросе. Суть его в том, что вместо записи `Order` вы храните записи `Order_Version` (и так для всех сущностей). Каждая запись - неизменяемая, это может проверять триггер и просто не давать этого делать. Каждое изменение - это добавление новой записи для новой версии сущности. Это немного похоже на подход с историей, но тут настоящая неизменность (immutability) записей и все версии одинаковы, т.е. нет различия между текущей и исторической.

Обычно не требуется большого изменения кода, который использует сущности, так как в большинстве кода все равно работаем ли мы с последней или с какой-то другой версией сущности. Мы по сути всегда используем какую-то потенциально устаревшую версию (так как ее могли поменять после того, как ее прочитали). И выделение этого аспекта явно идет на пользу коду. Обычно изменения требует небольшое количество кода, который собственно меняет сущности или которому нужно явно работать с последней версией, т.е. где были какие-то уже блокировки, чтобы синхронизировать конкурентный доступ.

При таком подходе отчет будет явно привязан к конкретной версии и даже если сущность изменилась, то это никак не влияет на отчет.

Конечно есть определенные накладные расходы и плата за гибкость, а именно, при создании отчета для какой-то версии, нужно выбирать связанные сущности по дате, т.е. нужно выбирать правильные версии связанных сущностей.