# Как сохранить старые данные пользователей в старых заказах

Tags: sql, база-данных, архитектура

Есть две таблицы с пользователями, и с заказами.
Структура таблиц не так важна, обычные данные пользователя ID, ФИО и т.д. и обычные данные по заказам с ценой товаром и привязкой к пользователю кто заказал по ID.
Какой подход применить, чтобы в случае изменения какого либо пользователя, в уже созданных заказах оставались те данные пользователя, которые были на момент создания заказа?

Есть пока две идеи.
Первая идея, это создать копию таблицы с пользователями, и при создании заказа копировать пользователя в эту таблицу, и заказ привязывать к нему. И при изменении пользователя в основной таблице, в копии останутся его старые данные.

И вторая идея, использовать одну таблицу с пользователями, но при изменении всегда создавать новую запись для этого же пользователя, а старую запись или записи помечать как скрытые.

Или может есть решения получше?

Comment: Как вариант, создать таблицу где будут храниться все изменения данных пользователя и тригер на таблицу пользователя. При UPDATE users - старые данные сохраняются в `old_data_users` с временной меткой. Имея временную метку в таблице заказов, Вы всегда сможете сопоставить любой заказ пользователя с его актуальными данными на тот момент.

Comment: Похожий вопрос обсуждался [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1198609/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94/1199016)

Comment: Использовать логику, пользователь сделавший заказ - относится к "заказу" а не к пользователю =) т.е. хранить данные о заказчике нужно вместе с заказом, а не в виде абстрактной связи(первый вариант - правильный для финансов). Конечно если вы работаете с финансами, иначе можете экономить и идти по второму варианту.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №1 (как делалось на бумаге)

При оформлении заказа в таблицы заказа добавлять не только ID, но и копировать текстовую информацию, которая должна остаться неизменной.

Вариант №2 (подсмотрено у ФИАС)

У записей, к которым может потребоваться доступ не только к текущему значению, но и к старому, фиксированному на определенный момент времени, делается два ID: один неизменный, который остается общим для всех исторических вариантов, второй - уникальный.

Например, это может выглядеть так:

```
GID; CID; Status; Value
123; 456; -     ; Иванов Иван 
123; 567; +     ; Иванов Иван Иванович
234; 345; -     ; Петров Петр
234; 395; -     ; Петров Петр Петрович
234; 678; +     ; Петров Пётр Петрович
```

GID (Global ID) - общий неизменный идентификатор, который соответствует некоторой сущности реального мира, в данном случае клиенту. Может быть FK на учетную запись клиента в системе или просто GUID.

CID (Current ID) - идентификатор текущего значения. Уникален в пределах таблицы. Именно он указывается в заказе. Или можно указать оба, но CID точно должен быть.

Status - Показывает состояние записи: актуальное/последнее значение или устаревшее/архивное. В зависимости от выбранной СУБД для ускорения выборки текущего значения по этому полю можно сделать кластеризацию, секционирование или ручное секционирование (текущие и архивные значения держать в двух разных таблицах, и сам столбец тогда не нужен).

Также можно дополнить другими полями для определения хронологии, например: порядковый номер, даты начала и конца действия, ссылки на предыдущее и следующее значения.

При «редактировании» записи, редактируемая запись помечается как более не актуальная, а новое значение записывается новой строкой с новым CID.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста по подробнее второй вариант, не до конца понял реализацию.

Comment: @Vladimir, дополнил ответ